# Trying to read a file in bash and grep for a substring, store that substring in an array

Tags: bash

I have a file named test.txt that has some data as follows:

```
*************************** 19. row ***************************
       created_at: 2018-07-02 19:57:58
       deleted_at: 2018-07-03 14:17:05
       serial_num: 1269043217201
*************************** 20. row ***************************
       created_at: 2018-07-02 19:57:58
       deleted_at: 2018-07-03 14:17:05
       serial_num: 1269043217202
```

I need to store all the serial numbers in an array. I've tried something basic to print:

```sh
filename="test.txt"
c=0
while read -r line
    do
       echo $line | grep serial_num | sed -n -e 's/serial_num: //p'
    done < "$filename"
```

This prints data like which looks good:

```
1280521737734
1280521737735
1280521737736
```

But when I add

```sh
sn=(echo $line | grep serial_num | sed -n -e 's/serial_num: //p')
echo $sn
```

This starts to print blank lines as well. How do I avoid that? 
Also doing this

```sh
servs[$c] = $sn
c=$(expr $c + 1)
```

returns

```
./test.sh: line 138: servs[0]: command not found
./test.sh: line 138: servs[1]: command not found
./test.sh: line 138: servs[2]: command not found
```

Comment: Err. `sn=( echo ... )` isn't creating an array with the output of the pipeline, it's creating an array with `echo` as its first element.

Comment: As another aside, shell-builtin math -- part of the POSIX sh standard since 1991 -- should be used in place of `expr`. That is, `c=$(( c + 1 ))`. This is *far* more efficient, as any command substitution (`$(...)`) requires `fork`ing off a subshell, and `/bin/expr` is an external command that then needs to be linked/loaded/etc.

Comment: (Also, backticks are only for spans of less than a line; for multi-line code formatting, use four-space indents; this also enables syntax highlighting).

Comment: Also, `servs[$c] = $sn` doesn't work because of the spaces around the `=`. It would be an assignment if you made it `servs[$c]=$sn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming bash 4.0 or newer:

```
readarray -t sn < <(awk '/serial_num:/ { print $2 }' <"$filename")
declare -p sn # print array content
```

With an older release:

```
sn=( )
while read -r line; do sn+=( "$line" ); done < <(awk '/serial_num:/ { print $2 }' <"$filename")
declare -p sn # print array content
```

With an older release, and in pure/native bash:

```
sn=( )
while IFS=$' \t\n' read -r key val; do
  [[ $key = serial_num: ]] && sn+=( "$val" )
done <"$filename"
declare -p sn
```